# Displaying Bootstrap on php date statements within end date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a qry that display records include a couple of dates from bootstrap datepicker and display on a project list page.

```
<td><b><?php echo date("M d, Y",strtotime($row['start_date'])) ?></b></td>
<td><b><?php echo date("M d, Y",strtotime($row['end_date'])) ?></b></td>
```

What i'd like to do is use the bootstrap badge class on these to display warning or danger class when the end date is two weeks out from the end date.

```
$today = date_create(date('m/d/Y'));
$end_date = strtotime($row['end_date']);
$diff = date_diff($today, $due)->format("%r%a");
```

From there i'm scratching my head.

```
if($end_date[$row['end_date']] =='$diff'){
echo "<span class='badge badge-danger'>{$end_date[$row['end_date']]}</span>";
```

an so on....